# How to Serialize a List of Primitive Objects with Kotlin Serializer?

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, polymorphism, kotlinx.serialization

I have a json response which  is a list of *list of objects*, I am trying to serialize it. How do I Serialize it with kotlin serializer?

```
{
  "body": [
    [
      "Fresho Apple - Royal Gala, Regular, 4 pcs",
      "Red",
      "146",
      82878,
      "Fruit",
      "40033823",
      4,
      600,
      36.5,
      "Turkey",
      "Best before 3 days from delivery date",
      "A combination of slightly tart-tasting skin and honey floral-tasting flesh, the Royal Gala apples, as the name suggests looks regal with beautiful golden-coloured streaks. Royal Gala apples are a good source of fibre and vitamin C, and they are a healthy snack or addition to a meal.",
      620,
      "https://www.bigbasket.com/cookbook/recipes/1611/apple-crumble-pie/",
      "2023-06-06T18:30:00Z",
      false,
      false,
      true
    ]
  ]
}
```

I have created the data class,

```
@Serializable
data class Response(
    val body: List<List<Any>>
)
```

```
@Serializable
data class Product(
  val title: String,
  val color: String,
  val price: String,
  val id: Int,
  val type: String,
  val ean: String,
  val count: Int,
  val weight: Int,
  val pricePerPiece: Float,
  val countryOfOrigin: String,
  val expiry: String,
  val Description: String,
  val nettWeight: Int,
  val link: String,
  val date: String,
  val isUnavailable: Boolean,
  val isCooked: Boolean,
  val isFruit: Boolean
)
```

I am stuck with this, how to convert the data type to a list so that we can map it to the Product?

Answer (score 0):

First, that's some highly non-idiomatic JSON (using a list to represent an object). So, if at all possible I would request whoever emits this JSON to rethink their format and use JSON objects instead (with all their benefits, such as order independence), in which case it would be as simple as:

```
@Serializable
data class Response(
    val body: List<Product>
)
```

If you have no control over it, you will have to [write a custom serializer](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#custom-serializers) for `body`, still using `List<Product>`, in which you map the list items to the expected properties in order.

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize this json content by using `JsonTransformingSerializer` API. it can transform one type of json element object to another json element object. More about it please read [official document](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#json-transformations).

The following is the specific implementation code for this question:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.builtins.ListSerializer
import kotlinx.serialization.json.*

@Serializable
data class Response(
    // specify your custom Serializer
    @Serializable(with = YourSerializer::class)
    val body: List<Product> // change type from List<List<Any>> to target type(List<Product>).
)

@Serializable
data class Product(
    val title: String,
    val color: String,
    val price: String,
    val id: Int,
    val type: String,
    val ean: String,
    val count: Int,
    val weight: Int,
    val pricePerPiece: Float,
    val countryOfOrigin: String,
    val expiry: String,
    val Description: String,
    val nettWeight: Int,
    val link: String,
    val date: String,
    val isUnavailable: Boolean,
    val isCooked: Boolean,
    val isFruit: Boolean
)

// implement your Serializer(transform origin json element to target json element)
object YourSerializer :
    JsonTransformingSerializer<List<Product>>(ListSerializer(Product.serializer())) {

    // Called when converting json string to target json element
    override fun transformDeserialize(element: JsonElement): JsonElement {
        return buildJsonArray {
            element.jsonArray.forEach { product ->
                add(
                    buildJsonObject {
                        put("title", product.jsonArray[0])
                        put("color", product.jsonArray[1])
                        put("price", product.jsonArray[2])
                        put("id", product.jsonArray[3])
                        put("type", product.jsonArray[4])
                        put("ean", product.jsonArray[5])
                        put("count", product.jsonArray[6])
                        put("weight", product.jsonArray[7])
                        put("pricePerPiece", product.jsonArray[8])
                        put("countryOfOrigin", product.jsonArray[9])
                        put("expiry", product.jsonArray[10])
                        put("Description", product.jsonArray[11])
                        put("nettWeight", product.jsonArray[12])
                        put("link", product.jsonArray[13])
                        put("date", product.jsonArray[14])
                        put("isUnavailable", product.jsonArray[15])
                        put("isCooked", product.jsonArray[16])
                        put("isFruit", product.jsonArray[17])
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }

    // Called when converting target json element to json string, you can override it if you need
    override fun transformSerialize(element: JsonElement): JsonElement {
        return super.transformSerialize(element)
    }
}

fun main() {
    val jsonString = """
        {
          "body": [
            [
              "Fresho Apple - Royal Gala, Regular, 4 pcs",
              "Red",
              "146",
              82878,
              "Fruit",
              "40033823",
              4,
              600,
              36.5,
              "Turkey",
              "Best before 3 days from delivery date",
              "A combination of slightly tart-tasting skin and honey floral-tasting flesh, the Royal Gala apples, as the name suggests looks regal with beautiful golden-coloured streaks. Royal Gala apples are a good source of fibre and vitamin C, and they are a healthy snack or addition to a meal.",
              620,
              "https://www.bigbasket.com/cookbook/recipes/1611/apple-crumble-pie/",
              "2023-06-06T18:30:00Z",
              false,
              false,
              true
            ]
          ]
        }
    """.trimIndent()
    println(Json.decodeFromString<Response>(jsonString))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It all depends on what your real question is. I couldn't really understand if this is a local JSON or NETWORK. If local: read it -> use [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html#example-json-serialization) as reference. Use encodeToString/decodeToString. If network you need Retrofit + kotlin Serialization. All well explained [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/use-kotlinx-serialization-library-to-parse-json-data-from-network-call/).

Btw. You can't parse it [your JSON] as `val body: List<List<Any>>`. It should be the obj type you need. i.e. `List<Product>`. Or `List<List<Product>>` if there is a nested list.

Good luck!

Comment: the rexponse is  from server of type ` List<List<Any>>` which i need to map to  `List<Product>`

Comment: Can you post json here?

Comment: You can cast Any to Ptoduct. Try flatMap or sth similar. But it's definitely wrong getting a 'List<List<Any>>' from a server.

Comment: No issues, i have fixed it by writing a custom Serializer. thank you for the input.

Comment: Hey @Elo1422, I need a similar solution, Can you post your solution here for a custom serializer for List<List<Any>>??